# Filling a square table with numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have integers from $1$ to $q$ and a square table of $p$ rows. Let $q \leq p^2$. Denote $C_i$ to be $i$-th column of the table. The table is filled with numbers from $1$ to $q$ in such way that $| C_1 \times C_1 \cup C_2 \times C_2 \cup \ldots \cup C_p \times C_p | = M \to \max$. Any integer may be used any number of times, but they all must be used at least once. How can I express $M$ as a function of $p$ and $q$? In other words, we want to make as much different pairs as possible, using elements from every column.

Here $C_i \times C_i = \{(x, y) \mid x, y \in C_i\}$.

For example, consider p = 3, q = 6. Then one of the optimal placements is
$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 4 & 1 \\
2 & 5 & 4 \\
3 & 6 & 2
\end{matrix},
$$
and we have $(1, 2), (1, 3)$ and $(2, 3)$ from the 1st column, $(4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)$ from the 2nd and $(1, 4), (2, 4)$ from the 3rd. Adding diagonal pairs $(i, i)$ and symmetric pairs $(i, j)$ for every $(j, i)$ we get 22 pairs total.

It is clear that from the columns, filled with distinctive numbers, that weren't used before, we get $2 C_p^2 + p = p^2$, where $C_p^2$ is a binomial coefficient. But as we get further in the table, numbers become used more than once and things get complicated.

Comment: What is $C_1 \times C_1$? Is it $\{(x,y) \mid x \in C_1 \wedge y \in C_1\}$?

Comment: Maybe an example would be appropriate.

Comment: I've updated the question according to the comments above.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: fix one of the variables $p,q$, calculate the answer by hand for small values of the other variable, and then look up the resulting sequence at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, oeis.org

Comment: Have you had a chance to follow up on my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to make up a table for $p=4$, $q$ from $2$ to $16$. No luck finding it on oeis.org. But I've noticed the following. Let us consider pairs $(a, b)$, but not the pairs $(b, a)$, $(a,a)$ and $(b,b)$. Then the sequence stabilizes to $C_{p^2}^2 - p^3(p-1)/2$. The first term is the total number of pairs and the second is the number of edges of the Turan graph with $p^2$ vertices and $p$ subsets. I'll try to extract more from this notice.